# Input.touchCount do not detect multitouch in iOS, but works fine for android

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am working on a project having multiple scenes in it. Problem is that one scene does not detect more than 1 touch in iOS device, but works fine for all android devices.

e.g.

```
void Update() 
{
    Debug.Log("touchCount: " + Input.touchCount); 
}
```

This function always returns 0 or 1, but only in that specific scene. I'm assuming something in the scene is affecting Unity's Input class.  I still don't have any idea why I can't get more than one touch on an iOS device.

NGUI is being used so maybe it has to do something with it?
Please advise

Comment: Does [Input.touches](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Input-touches.html) give the same result? (i.e. Input.touches.Length)

Comment: See also NGUI's [UICamera](http://www.tasharen.com/ngui/docs/class_u_i_camera.html) class. It contains `allowMultiTouch` and `touchCount`, maybe they'll work.

Comment: @ArttuPeltonen Yes it give the same result, I have also tried allowMultiTouch of NGUI camera but doesn't seems to allow multiple touch. Strange thing is that, everything works fine for android devices

Comment: Did you check this http://docs.unity3d.com/412/Documentation/ScriptReference/Input-multiTouchEnabled.html

Comment: @jpaari its enabled, i just checked